# Using Composite Database in AuraDB

Tags: neo4j

Can you create a composite database on an AuraDB server? I have an AuraDB server running.  Running the initial composite database command:

```
CREATE COMPOSITE DATABASE cineasts
```

Does not work on the neo4j version 5 instance when I run it through the neo4j Browser interface.  I try running it in the 'system' database, but I get this error:

```
Failed to create the specified database 'cineasts': The total limit of databases is already reached. To create more you need to either drop databases or change the limit via the config setting 'server.max_databases'
```

According to the documentation (https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/composite-databases/introduction/), I need to run this through "administrative commands".  I don't see how to access administrative commands on AuraDB.  Can I create composite databases on AuraDB?

Steps I followed:

1. I created a neo4j version 5 instance of a database on AuraDB.
2. I opened the neo4j browser to access the neo4j version 5 database.
3. I executed the `CREATE COMPOSITE DATABASE cineasts` command

I expected the neo4j Browser to accept the command and create the database for use in the subsequent alias creation steps.  Instead, it threw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create databases with AuraDB at the moment.

Comment: thank you @fbiville  for the update.  Will the composite databases be added to AuraDB in the future?